# Using Angular 2 Observable to display continuous stream of data

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular, couchbase, observable, couchbase-lite

I'm using a Couchbase Server as my database for my Angular 2 Web application. The data exchange happens through WebAPI's which talks to my CouchBase server.
I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it yet at the moment I'm querying(polling) for the WebAPI every 5 seconds in order to get updated list of data

```javscript
this.events = getRecentEvents(_siteUrl: String) {

    return Observable.interval(5000)
        .switchMap(() => this.http.get(_siteUrl).map((res: Response) => res.json()))
        .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I'm using the Observable object returned from this call to bind it to a list on the UI using async pipes

```html
<li class="item" *ngFor="#eventitem of events | async; #i = index"> 
  <h1>{{eventitem}} {{i}}</h1>
</li>
```

The question I have is, Is this the right way to do?
Am I not putting too much load on the server with repetitive WebAPI calls?
Can any one suggest a better alternative if this is not the way to handle continuous flow of data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the datasource.

If you on the server side can get notified when stuff happens, then I would suggest you use websockets or Server Sent Events (SSE) and create an Observable based on that steam.

That way the server sends the data when it becomes available, and you don't have to poll the server.

Try using the rxjs WebSocketSubject
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts

Otherwise your code for polling data looks good.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But is there a way for me to receive notifications on server side whenever there is a change in the database entries so that I can inform the server side code which in turn shall create an observable and can send the data changes to the client. At the moment I'm stuck here

Comment: it depends on what language / platform / library you are using for access couchbase.